# Populating a render method using a separate method in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

okay so everyone knows a separate mapping will do the trick of rendering a component in a React render method, something like this:

```
var listOfService = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
const listItems = listOfService.map((singleItem) =>
    <a className="style_class">{singleItem}</a>
);
```

and if you call `listItems` in the return of a render method, you will get the list and thats for a single list but I have a firebase firestore database and I want to loop through that database and get each document printed as a React Component I have called Service, I know that you can't use JSX inside a loop or if statement so I tried this:

```
renderServices() {
    let db = firebase.firestore();
    var details = [[]];
    db.collection('providers').get().then(function (snapshot) {

            snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {

                details.push(
                    [
                        doc.data().owner_name,
                        doc.data().experience,
                        doc.data().charges,
                        doc.data().address,
                        doc.data().home_service,
                        doc.data().highlights,
                        doc.data().certifications,
                        doc.data().specialty,
                        doc.data().facility
                    ]
                );
                //tried loading here Serivce, didn't work
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    details.map((singleDetail) =>
        (< Service details={singleDetail} />)
    );

}
```

so I tried this but its not working, I wrote some console logs and the data is coming in correctly. First I get the whole array of "`providers`" documents, that providers list gets passed on as "`snapshot`" so I loop through the snapshot with another function and that function is taking a single document called `doc` and then pushing it in the `var` called `details`, which is an array of arrays but! its not working, the array is not being populated even tho the data is there and therefore I am unable to map, any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I know that you can't use JSX inside a loop or if statement"? You are returning JSX from inside a loop already so are you sure thats what you mean?

Comment: I don't have much experience with firestore, but typically operations like this are async (based on your use of `then` I'd say this is the case). Is `details` still an empty array when you try to do the `map` by chance?

Comment: @BrianThompson yea the details array stays empty, its werid. I wrote console.log line right before details.push() and it shows every data but it just can't seem to pass the same data to the array of details. its like some sort of blockage and out of range issue

Comment: Create array of jsx element i.e: Service component in you code. Pass doc as details to service and return details array from function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, using ReactDOM.render method

first make a global array:

```
var Services = [];
```

and then add a DOM element where the array can be placed and rendered:

```
<div className="row d-flex justify-content-center" id='service-div'>

</div>
```

once you have the DOM element in place, let the page load, when the load completes, ComponentDidMount() is called, so put your method in there so its

```
ComponentDidMount(){
this.renderServices();}
```

now in this method, just populate the array and then use ReactDOM.render method to render it to a given DOM element

```
async renderServices() {

    let history = this.props.history; //in case the method can't access the history

    let db = firebase.firestore();
    selectedServices = this.props.location.state.selectedServices;

    var database = firebase.database();

    db.collection('providers').where('services', 'array-contains-any',
        selectedServices).get()
        .then(function (snapshot) {
            let idCount = 0;
            snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {

                let tempDetails = [];
                tempDetails.push(
                    doc.data().owner_name,
                    doc.data().experience,
                    doc.data().charges,
                    doc.data().address,
                    doc.data().home_service,
                    doc.data().highlights,
                    doc.data().certifications,
                    doc.data().specialty,
                    doc.data().facility,
                    doc.data().services,
                    doc.data().call_extension,
                    idCount.toString()
                );

                Services.push(<Service details={tempDetails} history={history} />); //adding the Service Component into a list
                idCount++;
            });
            ReactDOM.render(<div>{Services}</div>, document.getElementById('service-div')); //now rendering the entire list into the div
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);

        });



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your loading of data and the rendering of it because retrieving the data is `asynchronous` and rendering needs to be `synchronous`.

For example, in your case you are pushing the details into the array in the `then` callback - this will happen `async` to your main function so when you call `details.map` it is still empty (the callback hasn't fired to populate it).

Instead, you can load the data and store it in the state and then render it if it is available. Personally I prefer `async/await` but the same logic can be achieved with using `then` on promises:

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

// Load the data on initial load or setup the effect to fire when reload is needed
useEffect(() => {

  // Async function that loads the data and sets the state once ready
  const loadData = async () => {
    const details = [];
    try {
      const snapshot = await db.collection('providers').get();
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        details.push([
          // your details stuff
        ]);
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      // Handle any loading exceptions
    }

    setDetails(details);
  }
}, [])


// Render the available details, you could also add conditional rendering to check
// if the details are available or not yet
return (
  <div>
    {details.map((singleDetail) => (
      <Service details={singleDetail} />
    )};
  </div>
);
```

If you are using React classes instead of functional components, you would call the loading from `componentDidMount` and still set the state after it is loaded, then map over the state data when rendering.

Comment: ok I have done something similar and it seems to load all the data into the array but its not mapping like you wrote in the code, let me see whats up with that